# Différence entre « boulangère » et « boulangerie »

Tags: vocabulaire

Je fais un cours de français, où *bakery* est traduit par « boulangère », mais quand j'étais en France, je me souviens que les *bakeries* s’appelaient « boulangeries ».

Quel est le terme le plus correct?
Quelle est la différence entre « boulangère » et « boulangerie » ?

Comment: Peux-tu donner le contexte ? Il faut savoir s'il s'agit du lieu (l'endroit où on achète le pain), où d'un adjectif (i.e. bakery-style something or other)

Comment: @Laure: le lieu, où on produit et vend le pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le magasin où on achète du pain, en France (je ne peux rien dire sur d'autres pays francophones, et ça peut être différent ailleurs), est une boulangerie.

Boulangère peut-être **un nom** : dans ce cas il s'agit de la personne qui vend le pain dans la boulangerie, c'est un métier.

Boulangère peut-être **un adjectif** et  en anglais ça correspond à l'emploi du mot *bakery* employé comme adjectif : par exemple « des pommes boulangères » (une certaine façon de préparer des pommes de terre), se traduit en anglais par *bakery-style potatoes*.

Il y aussi la *levure boulangère* et là l'anglais fait référence au métier (***baker's*** yeast) et le français emploie l'adjectif.

Les magasins ont souvent des noms, et on peut aussi imaginer une boulangerie qui s'appelle « La boulangère ».

Mais si ton livre dit que le magasin où on vend le pain est « **une** boulangère », alors c'est une erreur.

Comment: Je confirme pour le Québec, "boulangerie" est le bon terme. Je dois noter cependant qu'il n'existe que très peu de boulangeries ici, au contraire de la France. Les épiceries s'occupent de vendre ces produits.

Answer (score 1):

***Bakery*** est une bonne traduction de **boulangerie**.

Une **boulangère** est soit une ***(female) baker***, soit la ***baker's wife*** et souvent les deux.

Comment: @jiliagre: Merci, c'est clair! Boulangère n'est donc pas un lieu, mais une profession.